# How to get Top 5 records in SqLite?

Tags: sqlite, select

I have tried this which did not work.

```
select top 5 * from [Table_Name]
```

Comment: the meaning of TOP x records makes no sense applied to an entire table or select, for that SQL uses ORDER BY and LIMIT as pointed in all answers here. TOP x records makes sense when talking about groups or "windows". This has been introduced in sqlite in 3.25.0 (2018) https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html. A very simple example of that. Selecting the top orders by date could be done with the SQL: "SELECT date, desc, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY amount DESC) AS topn", when we build a new field topn that will have the values 1, 2, 3 etc for the top orders of each date....

Answer (score 677, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 48):

An equivalent statement would be

```
select * from [TableName] limit 5
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 39):

```
select price from mobile_sales_details order by price desc limit 5
```

Note: i have mobile_sales_details table

syntax

```
select column_name from table_name order by column_name desc limit size.
```

if you need top low price just remove the keyword desc from order by

Answer (score 32):

```
select * from [Table_Name] limit 5
```

Answer (score 32):

TOP and square brackets are specific to Transact-SQL. In ANSI SQL one uses LIMIT and backticks (`).

```
select * from `Table_Name` LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: LIMIT is not ANSI SQL. The ANSI SQL way is FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY. Also double quotes are used for delimited identifiers, e.g. "Table_Name".

Answer (score 8):

```
Select TableName.* from  TableName DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Improper use of `DESC`. Has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer works, EXCEPT when you need to add a where clause.
If you need a where clause and still need to limit that where clause to the top 5 records, then you need to create a subselect like the following.

Why? because in my case the where-clause excludes some of the top 5 records.  You still get a limit of 5 records, but they won't be the first 5 records.

```
        SELECT sum(quantity) as total
          FROM (
                    SELECT quantity, weight
                      FROM mytable                 
                  order by id
                     limit 5
               ) AS T
         where weight > 2
```

Comment: I did this and still worked: SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE COLUMN_A = '1' LIMIT 10;

Answer (score -2):

Replace only YOUR table name[TABLE_NAME] and use.

```
"select * from "+TABLE_NAME+ " LIMIT " +5;
```

Comment: This suffers from SQL injection easily if either the table name or the limit come from untrusted sources