# How to get first/top row of the table in Sqlite via Sql Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to fetch the first/top row of a table in a Sqlite database.

But my program throws an SQLException "Sqlite Syntax Error: Syntax error near '1' " for the query that I am using:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
```

That I guess is a syntax particularly for MS SQL SERVER and MS ACCESS. Right now I am using.

```
SELECT *
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
LIMIT 1
```

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Should be mentioned that developer should not depend on physical order of records in the Table. This is danger idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Top 5 records in SqLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728999/how-to-get-top-5-records-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 185):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE ORDER BY ROWID ASC LIMIT 1
```

Note: Sqlite's row id references are [detailed here](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Answer (score 32):

`LIMIT 1` is what you want.  Just keep in mind this returns the first record in the result set regardless of order (unless you specify an `order` clause in an outer query).

Comment: `LIMIT 1` executes the full query, and then discards the unneeded results. There are several mailing list discussions about it and `COUNT(*)`. It is different than finding the first matching record with `TOP 1`. Once the first record is found the query can stop and return the result.