# How can I get 10 first records of join tables in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

How can I get just 10 first records of Nemayeh.Nemayeh fields in Sqlite?

```
SELECT
  Keyword,
  Nemayeh.Nemayeh

FROM
  (SELECT
     Keyword.Id,
     Keyword.Keyword
   FROM Keyword
   ORDER BY Keyword.Keyword ASC
   LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  ) AS tmp

INNER JOIN KeyWord_Nemayeh
        ON KeyWord_Nemayeh.Id_Keyword = tmp.Id

INNER JOIN Nemayeh
        ON Nemayeh.Id = KeyWord_Nemayeh.Id_Nemayeh

ORDER BY 1,2
```

For Example :

```
Key1 Nem1_1
Key1 Nem1_2
Key1 Nem1_3
.
.
.
Key1 Nem1_10
Key2 Nem2_1
Key2 Nem2_2
.
.
.
Key2 Nem2_10
```

Comment: So you want a result table which has at least 10, but not more than 10 **distinct** `Nemayeh.Nemayeh` value? (Appending `LIMIT 10` to your query would be too simple :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much what biziclop said but should work.

```
SELECT
  Keyword,
  Nemayeh.Nemayeh
FROM
  (SELECT Keyword.Id,Keyword.Keyword 
   FROM Keyword
   ORDER BY Keyword.Keyword ASC
   LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) AS tmp

INNER JOIN KeyWord_Nemayeh ON KeyWord_Nemayeh.Id_Keyword = tmp.Id

INNER JOIN Nemayeh ON Nemayeh.Id = KeyWord_Nemayeh.Id_Nemayeh

ORDER BY 1,2 LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: I get 10 'Keyword', then I want get 10 'Nemayeh' for every 'Keyword'. Please see my edit post.

Comment: Okay I understand... I have tried to look up if you can create functions in SQLite but I didn't find any information on this. Otherwise I think what you want to achieve is hard in sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Keyword,... FROM...
```

Comment: OK, sorry :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728999/how-to-get-top-5-records-in-sqlite