# Exception while deleting row

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an Sqlite db where I'm limiting it to 10 max rows of latest entries. Logic is when inserting any new entry I check the number of rows. If there are already 10 rows, it will delete the oldest entered row and add a new one. But I'm getting error `SQLiteException: near "BYid": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM profORDER BYid LIMIT 1`. Is this because of any space mismatch or query error?

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

// Profile Settings table name
private static final String TABLE_PROF = "prof";

// Profile Settings information names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";


public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_PROF_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROF + "("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_NAME+" TEXT,  "+KEY_MOBILE+" TEXT" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_PROF_TABLE);

    Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PROF);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}


/**
 * Storing Prof_settings details in database
 * */
public void addProfile(String name, String mobile){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    values.put(KEY_MOBILE, mobile);

    int count = getProfilesCount();

    if(count == 10) {

        String DELETE_ROW = "DELETE FROM " +TABLE_PROF+ "ORDER BY" +KEY_ID+" LIMIT 1";

        db.execSQL(DELETE_ROW); // will delete oldest record
    }

    long id = db.insert(TABLE_PROF, null, values); // insert to 1st row
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "New profile settings inserted into sqlite: " + id);

}




/**
 * Getting Profile Settings data from database
 * */
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getProfDetails()
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * " + " FROM " + TABLE_PROF + " GROUP BY " + KEY_NAME + " ORDER BY " + KEY_MOBILE + " COLLATE NOCASE;", null);
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PROF;
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while (res.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> hashmap= new HashMap<String, String>();
        hashmap.put("id", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
        hashmap.put("name", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
        hashmap.put("mobile", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_MOBILE)));

        array_list.add(hashmap);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}

public int getProfilesCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PROF;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int cnt = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return cnt;
}

/**
 * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void deleteUsers() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_PROF, null, null);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all profile info from sqlite");
}
```

}

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause can't be used with `DELETE`.  By the way, didn't you ask a similar question to this a few days ago?

Comment: Just put space before and after `ORDER BY`.

Comment: `String DELETE_ROW = "DELETE FROM "  + TABLE_PROF + " ORDER BY " + KEY_ID + " LIMIT 1";`

Comment: Yes, I asked yesterday and I'm still getting exception. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
"DELETE FROM " +TABLE_PROF+ "ORDER BY" +KEY_ID+" LIMIT 1";
```

to

```
"DELETE FROM " +TABLE_PROF+ " ORDER BY " +KEY_ID+" LIMIT 1";
```

Just put space before and after `ORDER BY`.

And As @TimBiegeleisen pointed out, `LIMIT` clause doesn't work with `DELETE`.

One workaround is this -

```
"DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PROF
+ " WHERE someColumn in ( "
+ "    SELECT someColumn FROM " + TABLE_PROF + " ORDER BY " + KEY_ID + " LIMIT 1"
+ ")";
```

Comment: Yes, I think LIMIT won't work with DELETE as I'm getting exception `near "ORDER": syntax error (code 1):` @Shreyash

Comment: Also checking this link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619424/delete-all-but-top-n-from-database-table-in-sqlite-for-java-android) as this also shows similar logic

Comment: What is `someColumn` here? Can I use any Column name (like KEY_NAME) to delete first row?

Comment: @SomnathPal `someColumn` can be any column which is **Unique**. I suggest you take Primary Key.

Comment: So shouldn't `someColumn` be outside of double quotes?

Comment: Your answer is absolutely working. Except that `someColumn` should be outside double quotes. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SomnathPal `someColumn` is not a variable here. So I put it inside quotes. However, you can define a variable and put it outside, No problem there. BTW Your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
String DELETE_ROW = "DELETE FROM " +TABLE_PROF+ "ORDER BY" +KEY_ID+" LIMIT 1";
```

This should be

```
String DELETE_ROW = "DELETE FROM " +TABLE_PROF+ " ORDER BY " +KEY_ID+" LIMIT 1";
```

like this.
Note the space before ORDER and after BY.