# Improve an SQLite query that returns many records

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, petapoco

I have a query that gets executed on an SQLite database table from a WPF application; this query can return a large amount of records (from about 80000 up to about 1 million) which I down-sample before displaying it.
It takes about 10 seconds to return 700000 records, can it be optimized in some way?

The WHERE clause filters the records by a date time column:

```
(WHERE CollectedOn > @startTime AND CollectedOn < @endTime)
```

and I'm selecting all of the 18 columns of the table.
Does the number of columns influence the executing time of the query?

Thanks for the comments. I should point out a few more things:

The data I collect needs to be displayed in a chart; since I want to display only 600 points my algorithm picks one point every 600 from those 700000 records. Can this be achieved in a single query?

Comment: yes the number of columns will influence the executing time.  but if you are down sampling before displaying and you don't want all 700,000 records how many do you want?  you can LIMIT the number of records returned as well....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728999/how-to-get-top-5-records-in-sqlite

Comment: Agreed - do you downsampling logic in SQL - no point in pulling things just to throw them away.

Comment: It seems like *THAT* may actually be your question - if you need help translating your logic to SQL, just ask!

Comment: I added some clarification to the question.

Comment: Read [Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) to understand how indexes can be used. But reading that many rows always is slow; you have to find a way to let the database filter out the unwanted rows.

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the things I would consider:

- Further narrowing down the number of returned records (you said that you down-sample before displaying... can you down-sample within the database or even the WHERE clause)?
- Do you really need all the records at once? Maybe paging would help (see [LIMIT and OFFSET](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_limit_clause.htm))
- You could try to use an index to speed up your query. Use [EXPLAIN](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) to find out what your query does exactly... afterwards you can optimize joins and selections (also use indices for joins).

Narrowing down the attributes is always a good thing to do (instead of just returning all columns), but at least for simple queries (no subselects), it will have less influence than selecting the right rows using the WHERE clause. Also search for "selection" and "projection" about this issue.

Comment: You can pick every 600th record. That should be quite easy using sqlite's special attribute `ROWID` and the modulo function in the where clause. Maybe something like (untested) `WHERE ROWID % 600 = 0`