# SQL instruction TOP doesn't work on sqldf in R

Tags: r, sqldf

I am trying to use a SQL instruction on R to JOIN on the nearest past date.

I have the table JOIN :

```
        CODE   DATECREATION      PRIX
1         4   2015-12-31           813
2         4   2015-12-31           824
3         4   2016-07-20           864
4         4   2016-07-22           318.61
5         4   2016-07-22           256.52
```

and table TGA :

```
     CODE      DATE         TGA
1     10      2012-06-01    19.29
2     20      2012-06-01    19.29
3     21      2012-06-01    19.29
4     23      2012-06-01    19.29
5     35      2012-06-01    19.29
```

I want to join that dataframes by CODE and DATE. 
But the dates are not the same, I want all lines of table JOIN, and take the nearest date of TGA to add the column TGA on the dataframe JOIN

I tried :

```
TEST = sqldf("SELECT A.*,
             (SELECT TOP 1 B.TGA
              FROM dataTGA B
              WHERE B.DATEDEBUTAPPLICATION < A.DATECREATION
              ORDER BY B.DATEDEBUTAPPLICATION DESC) AS TGA 
             FROM JOIN A")
```

The error is :

```
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : near "1": syntax error
```

And I didn't add yet the condition on the codes

Comment: This is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728999/how-to-get-top-5-records-in-sqlite

Comment: It is not the same problem. Since I am on R and not sqlLite. Using the LIMIT instead of TOP `TEST = sqldf("SELECT A.*, (SELECT B.TGAP FROM dataTGAP B WHERE B.DATEDEBUTAPPLICATION < A.DATECREATION ORDER BY B.DATEDEBUTAPPLICATION DESC LIMIT 5 ) AS TGAP FROM JOIN A")` gives me the error `Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  near "JOIN": syntax error`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Top 5 records in SqLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728999/how-to-get-top-5-records-in-sqlite)

Comment: I don't think you can use `LIMIT` in a subquery in the select clause.  Let me see if I can refactor for you.

Comment: mlegge not the same thing. I am not working with SqlLite but the package sqldf or R. It would be so cool Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: It sure looks to me like you're sending these queries to a SQLite engine...therefore you are using SQLite.

Comment: Ok my bad, but it didn't change the fact that I can't use LIMIT in a subquery...

Comment: Please edit the SQL query so that it uses SQLite dialect.

Comment: Not every correlated subquery can be rewritten as a join, and the one you have may not be rewritable.  But you should edit your question, show some sample data, along with what your query is supposed to be doing.  Maybe there is still another workaround.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Do you have some ideas ?

Comment: I upvoted your question, this is as much as I think I can do.

Comment: (1) `TOP` is not a valid keyword in SQLite which is the default backend used by `sqldf`, i.e. if you do not specify an alternate backend. You can use `limit` in SQLite and that does work in subqueries.  For example, `sqldf("select * from (select * from iris limit 1)")` works. (2) `DATEDEBUTAPPLICATION` is not a column in any of the inputs.

Comment: I tried with LIMIT in subquery but it didn't work. I tried the instruction `TEST = sqldf("SELECT A.*, (SELECT B.TGAP FROM dataTGAP B WHERE B.DATEDEBUTAPPLICATION < A.DATECREATION ORDER BY B.DATEDEBUTAPPLICATION DESC LIMIT 1) AS TGAP FROM JOIN A")` and it gives me the error `Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : near "JOIN": syntax `

Comment: @G.Grothendieck But the nature of the query requires a subquery in the select clause, along with `LIMIT`.  This is a tough one to refactor; if we had exact data and a SQLite console, it might be possible.

Comment: That is not the source of the error.  There are at least two other errors in the SQL statement (1) use of an SQL keyword as a table name, (2) there is no table called `dataTGAP` in the question.

Comment: SQLite is not very good at inner queries. Try to write your query without inner queries. And edit the question above how far you have reworked the question.